# php slow lag when login

Tags: php, performance

i am developing a new section on my site and ive notice a small latency when login. on my computer it works great but when i put it to th eserver it is slower. the login process is slower on the server and not on my cmoputer.

half second to 1 second slower

i have doubt on my hosting that is not as fast as they say since on my computer its fast.

is there a way i can monitor the speed of the server `command line` or `php script` i can run to find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put these three lines of code in various places in your script (replacing "foo" with a description of where you place it in the code):

```
$h = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($h, 'foo: ' . microtime(true));
fclose();
```

Then, run your script, and you can see which part is slow.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the script, put

```
<?php
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
$start_time = microtime_float();
```

and at the end

```
$exec_time = microtime_float() - $start_time;
echo 'Page loaded in: ' . $exec_time . 'seconds';
?>
```

Compare your local copy with the remote copy.